# Android - lightweight resources for displaying visual plots of data that are continuously updated?

Tags: android, plot

I'm writing an Android app that will be receiving a stream of data, and I want to display a graph/plot of all the data. A new set of all the data to be graphed will come in every second, and I want my graph to be updated when this happens. Are there any good libraries/resources for graphs/plots that will be updated frequently, as opposed to static plots?

I've looked at ChartDroid and AChartEngine, and they look pretty good, but I'm not sure if there are better resources for plotting things that will be continuously updated, or if I should just use those to remake a new graph every second. (Or perhaps ChartDroid and AChartEngine have this capability already and I just didn't see it?)

Thanks.

EDIT: Also, it would be ideal if I didn't have to use an external library (could just copy source code).

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use AChartEngine for this.
Whenever you add data to the dataset (model), you can call repaint() on your GraphicalView reference and it will update the view.